# How to use where clause on methods rather than database columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, postgresql, activerecord

One problem I often run into in Rails is this:

Let's say I have an `invoices` table with a `date` and a `days` column.

How can I retrieve all invoices which are due?

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.due
    where("due_date > ?", Date.today) # this doesn't work because there is no database column "due_date"
  end

  private 

  def due_date
    date + days
  end

end
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this without having to add a database column `due_date` to my invoices table?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which database? They all handle date manipulation differently (because we have standards for this sort of thing after all :).

Comment: You can do it with kdeisz's answer but it will be very slow compared to sql query. Postgresql has hstore that works like a charm.

Comment: @muistooshort: Actually, it would be great if it would apply to as many databases as possible. I am developing on SQLite but might be deploying to Postgres later.

Comment: Database portability is a myth. Start developing on top of the same database you'll be deploying on right now or your production deployment will probably be a big mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, [adding an integer to a `date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE) adds that many days:

```
date '2001-09-28' + integer '7' = date '2001-10-05'
```

so you can simply say:

```
where('due_date + days > :today', :today => Date.today)
```

However, SQLite doesn't really have a `date` type at all, it stores dates as ISO 8601 strings. That means that adding a number to a date will end up concatenating the strings and that's sort of useless. SQLite does have a [`date` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) though:

> **date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)**
>   [...]
>   All five date and time functions take a time string as an argument. The time string is followed by zero or more modifiers.

so you can say things like `date('2014-01-22', '+ 11 days')` to do your date arithmetic. That leaves you with this:

```
where("date(due_date, '+' || days || ' days') > :today", :today => Date.today)
```

Thankfully, ISO 8601 date strings compare properly as strings so `>` still works.

Now you're stuck with two versions of the same simple query. You could check what sort of thing `self.connection` is to differentiate between dev/SQLite and production/PostgreSQL or you could look at `Rails.env.production?`. This of course leaves a hole in your test suite.

I think you should stop developing on top of SQLite if you intend on deploying on top of PostgreSQL and you should do that right now to minimize the pain and suffering. The truth is that any non-trivial application will be wedded to the database you use in production or you will have to expend significant effort (including running your test suite against all the different databases you use) to maintain database portability. Database independence is a nice idea in theory but wholly impractical unless someone is prepared to cover the non-trivial costs (in time and treasure) that such independence requires. ORMs won't protect you from the differences between databases unless your application is yet another "15 minute blog" toy.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.due
    Invoice.all.select { |invoice| invoice.due_date > Date.today }
  end

  private 

  def due_date
    date + days
  end

end
```

Comment: This kinda works but returns an array and not an ActiveRecord relation which is not ideal for me.

Comment: @muistooshort do you have a solution? Or just commentary?